# Changing specific elements of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got a piece of working code but am trying to significantly shorten it and am out of my depth. In specific, I'm trying to force an operation on several elements on a list using the following code:

```
PointListT = {{0, RBase}, {Middle, RMiddle}, {Height, RTop}};
ReplacePart[PointListT, {#, 2}, PointListT[[#, 2]] - GlassThick] & /@ {1, 2, 3}
```

But this does not work, ideas?

Comment: If the code doesn't work, and you haven't specified what you're trying to do, we can't help! Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish and what the desired output would be for a sample input?

Comment: You probably meant `ReplacePart[list, a -> b]` and not `ReplacePart[list, a, b]`. There is a three-argument form, but it is undocumented and the values you passed don't fit it. Stick to the documented form.  Also, `ReplacePart` doesn't modify the list in-place. It *returns* a modified list.

Comment: If you want to subtract GlassThick from the first element of each sublist, use `{#1 - GlassThick, #2}& @@@ list`.  `MapAt[# - GlassThick &, PointListT, {{All, 1}}]` will also work.  Try not to use capitalized names like `GlassThick` and `PointListT` because they may collide with builtins. Use names starting with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pointListT = {{0, RBase}, {Middle, RMiddle}, {Height, RTop}};
```

Doing it with replacement.

```
pointListT /. {a_, b_} -> {a, b - GlassThick}]
```

Doing it with `Apply` at level 1

```
{#1, #2 - GlassThick} & @@@ pointListT
```

Both give

> `{{0, -GlassThick + RBase}, 
>   {Middle, -GlassThick + RMiddle}, 
>   {Height, -GlassThick + RTop}}`

Comment: This is super helpful, thanks!